# quadToUnitSquare is undefined for the type PerspectiveFilter

Tags: java, image-processing

I face two errors in the below code,

1. quadToUnitSquare is undefined for the type PerspectiveFilter
2. setClip is undefined for the type PerspectiveFilter

What could be the reason/solution?

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    java.util.List<Point> corners = apertureImage.getCorners();

                    PerspectiveFilter filter = new PerspectiveFilter();

                     **filter.quadToUnitSquare**(
                            (float)(corners.get(0).getX() / width), (float)(corners.get(0).getY() / height),
                            (float)(corners.get(1).getX() / width), (float)(corners.get(1).getY() / height),
                            (float)(corners.get(2).getX() / width), (float)(corners.get(2).getY() / height),
                            (float)(corners.get(3).getX() / width), (float)(corners.get(3).getY() / height));
                    **fliter.setClip(true);**
                    filter.setInterpolation(TransformFilter.BILINEAR);

                    BufferedImage corrected = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(null), bi.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    filter.filter(bi, corrected);
                    final int newSize = Math.min(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
                    final BufferedImage target = CaptureUtils.createBufferedImage(
                                    corrected.getScaledInstance(newSize, newSize, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH),
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                    // write stretched image to the screen:
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            apertureImage.setImage(target);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What library are you using that gives you a `PerspectiveFilter`, and where is the documentation that says it contains those methods?

Comment: http://vrl.mihosoft.eu/api-doc/latest/eu/mihosoft/vrl/ext/com/jhlabs/image/PerspectiveFilter.html